# Java equivalent of the Kotlin's secondary constructor "apply"

Tags: java, android, kotlin, constructor, kotlin-android

I am having a problem. I need something similar to  Kotlin's secondary constructor "apply" in Java.
Kotlin:

```
private val paint = Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG).apply {
    color = Color.YELLOW;
    style = Paint.Style.STROKE
    strokeWidth = 5.0f
}
```

I expect something like this in Java:

```
private Paint paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG).apply{
    color = Color.YELLOW
    style = Paint.Style.STROKE
    strokeWidth = 5.0f
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
private Paint paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG)

    paint.color = Color.YELLOW
    paint.style = Paint.Style.STROKE
    paint.strokeWidth = 5.0f
```